# How can I create a radially-symmetric surface from a profile in ArcGIS 10?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, 3d

I have created an expected profile for a radially-symmetric feature (an impact crater) using numerical modelling and would like to compare this with the actual topography (a DEM).

My plan is to do this by making a surface/3d polygon based on the profile and then subtracting one from the other. However, I can't figure out a way to create a surface based on the profile. Is there a way to do this in ArcGIS 10?

Answer (score 1):

a radially symmetric surface could be seen as a function of the distance. so you could draw a point at the center of your crater, then compute the distance to the point ([euclidan distance](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000001p000000)) and apply your function of the distance using [map algebra](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z7000000). If your function is too complex, the workaround is to [reclassify](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=reclassify) your distance from point.